# Why is EqualityComparer<string>.Default not working?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, iequalitycomparer

```
var dic = context.Treasure.Include("TreasureShare")
  .Where(t => t.TreasureShare.IsShared && t.TreasureShare.EvaluationContent.Contains(keyword))
  .ToDictionary(t => t.ProductUrl, t => t.ProductId, EqualityComparer<string>.Default);
```

I got an error:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

So why the equalitycomparer not work, and how to use a equalitycomparer to get different records while querying to database.

**Updated:**

I know IEqualityComparer  can only be executed locally, but I didn't get an error like:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Panli.Service.Share.DataAccess.DbData.Treasure] Distinct[Treasure](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Panli.Service.Share.DataAccess.DbData.Treasure], System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[Panli.Service.Share.DataAccess.DbData.Treasure])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

except I change the codes to below:

```
dic = context.Treasure.Include("TreasureShare")
  .Where(t => t.TreasureShare.IsShared && t.TreasureShare.EvaluationContent.Contains(theme))
  .Distinct(new TreasureEqualityComparer()).ToDictionary(t => t.ProductUrl, t => t.ProductId);
```

This is my TreasureEqualityComparer:

```
public class TreasureEqualityComparer : EqualityComparer<Treasure>
{
    public override bool Equals(Treasure x, Treasure y)
    {
        return x.ProductUrl.ToLower() == y.ProductUrl.ToLower();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Treasure obj)
    {
        return obj.ProductUrl.ToLower().GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

So why not throw an exception just like the `Distinct()`  when I use `ToDictionary(..)` which has an `IEqualityComparer` param ?  Anyone can explain this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary key has to be unique. In this case you are using ProductUrl as dictionary key and ProductId as value, unfortunately as the error indicated there are more then one records in Table having same ProductUrl. So you can't use it as a dictionary key.

Comment: I'm using a default equalityComaprer to skip the same productUrl, did i use it in a wrong way ?

Comment: Yes is think so. EqualityComparer there doesn't specify any additional requirement about the data to linq query. Actiually, `ToDictionary(...)` only telling linq to convert query result to Dictionary format, thats it. The query itself didn't tell anything about getting only different data.

Comment: then what's the meaning of the overload in ToDictionary() that has a IEqualityComparer param ?

Comment: I think, it tells how to match dictionary key when you asked for an element with key "a", and also when the program comparing two keys on checking if any duplicate keys in the Dictionary. So as I said, it add specification for the Dictionary resulted, not for the query.

Comment: And about the update, ToDictionary is executed locally, thats why you didn't get the same error. All data pulled from database based on what you specify in the query before .ToDictionary part. And then the data tranformed to a Dictionary format as the execution reach .ToDictionary part.

Answer (score 1):

> So why not throw an exception?

The `ToDictionary` part is executed in memory. This is apparent when you investigate the SQL that is executed: nothing that shows any preparation for a conversion to `Dictionary`.

The query expression with `Distinct` on the other hand is translated into SQL as a whole (except it isn't because it fails). EF tries to let the database do the hard work of returning distinct values, but of course a comparer can't be translated into SQL, so this overload of `Distinct()` is not supported.

As for the duplicate key: apparently there are duplicate URL's (ignoring case). Maybe you should use `group by`.